# In Marketing cloud is there a way to create a Filtered DE from the All Subscribers List?

Tags: marketing-cloud

In Marketing cloud is there a way to create a Filtered Data Extension from the All Subscribers List without Exporting first and then importing into a new data extension and then filtering that?

Comment: Markus, is there a way to also query the profile attributes added to the All Subs table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Automation Studio to create an automation containing a query activity, that queries All Subscribers and writes it to a Data Extension. In this step you can already add your filter criteria to the query definition. If you want to build multiple filtered Data Extensions, you can also create an unfiltered version using the query and than create filtered data extensions from this copy of All Subscribers.

**Filtered using query:**

For example if you want to add any subscriber to the filtered data extension who has an email address ending with "@example.com", you could use a query similar to:

```
SELECT 
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress 
FROM _subscribers 
WHERE EmailAddress LIKE '%@example.com'
```

**Unfiltered in query *(filter needs to be done using filtered data extension)*:**

When adding all subscribers unfiltered to a data extension you could use this query (add the desired fields to the query):

```
SELECT 
    SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress 
FROM _subscribers
```

Comment: @AlvinPropst You are welcome! If my answer solved your problem, please mark my answer as accepted, so anyone can see that this is the correct solution. Thank you!